# Bootstrap layout breaks when column exceeds 12 but they are proportion to 12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a layout with 8 block which use col-*-6 of bootstrap grid. i put them inside a single row as its going to take 4 lines of row as they are all contain 6 grid column. However, my layout breaks as the columns has not equal height. I know i could use 4 row class to put 2 block of 6 grid column to solve this problem. But, my question is, is that only way to achieve this or i'm missing something in my current approach. Here is the code sample -

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Travel / 5 April 2015</h4>
        <h1>Make Some Changes To Do It With Us.</h1>
        <p>
           Nullam quis ante. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/posts/1.jpg" alt="post image">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/posts/1.jpg" alt="post image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Travel / 5 April 2015</h4>
        <h1>Make Some Changes To Do It With Us.</h1>
        <p>
           Nullam quis ante. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Travel / 5 April 2015</h4>
        <h1>Make Some Changes To Do It With Us.</h1>
        <p>
           Nullam quis ante. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/posts/1.jpg" alt="post image">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you aware of [How Bootstrap Grid System Works](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)?

Comment: Yes, i've mentioned in question, but please let me know if i something missing.@Ganesh Salunkhe

Comment: As much I know, One row should total col-*-12 which is not true in your case.

Comment: yes, i know that and mentioned in my question. but, as two of them are taking 12 grid column, new column should take new line. This is why, tried to do something like this. But if this is not a way accomplish my layout, i'll not do it.

Comment: Probably I'm not able to explain it properly. But one row can contain max 12 columns only. You should close row and re-open if needed.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh Salunkhe ! I understand what you men.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've got the answer today. the solution of my problem is to use .clearfix !

in my scenario, my layout was breaking for different height of each column, in that case if i use

after each column that sum up to 12.